# How can change ip address of server when use file_get_contents

Tags: php, sockets, proxy, ip

For example, my ip server is 200.231.123.11
when I use file_get_contents() this ip get page.
but I want change this to Dynamic ip. (ip changed automatically)
I use this code in my php:
**UPDATED**

```
<?php
//Define your context options
$opts = array(
           'http' => array(
                        'proxy' => 'tcp://221.10.40.238:80',
                        'request_fulluri' => true,
                     ),
);

// create the context...
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// ...and use it to fetch the data
echo file_get_contents('http://www.example.com', false, $context);

?>
```

but not working and still get page with real ip (200.231.123.11).

Comment: Please explain what you think `'bindto' => '192.168.0.102:0'` should do. It most likely _does_ work, but not like you expect it to.

Comment: this if have two ip server. but i haven't two ip. i want create it automatically like that use vpn

Comment: What does _"i want create it automatically like that use vpn"_ mean? What do you want to create automatically, and what does VPN have to do with that?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to pretend to send a request from a different IP address, then you will actually have to send the request from a different IP address. TCP/IP is a fundamental addressing mechanism to deliver data packets across the web. If you want to communicate with someone, you both need to know each others actual addresses, else you won't be able to talk to each other.

You will need to assign an actual different IP address to the server and/or use proxy servers which can forward the request and the response on behalf of your server. You can't simply pretend to have a different address.

Comment: Besides that, OP doesn't seem to get NAT. He seems to be trying to make it look like the request came from the requesting server's LAN IP.

Comment: i want create it automatically like that use vpn

Comment: @kelly I have no idea what you're saying.